# What is this plastic ring called on a tripod and can I get a replacement?

Tags: terminology, tripod, repair-parts

[image: tripod ring]

I have a Hama Compact Traveller Tripod in which the plastic ring that inserts where the tripod head and metal tube goes is broken. Is it possible to get a replacement for this as I do not wish to purchase a new tripod.

Comment: You might take it into your local hardware store to see if there are bushings close enough in size to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a plastic ferrule.  Best bet would be to contact Hama directly. It looks like a cheap enough part and small enough they might mail you one.